# How can I avoid that the inherited class have to pass the base class constructor parameter

Tags: c#

I have a base classe and an inheriting child class.

The base classes constructor accepts a parameter which I do not want to pass from my child constructor.

The parameter is a generic `List<MyInterface>`

Is that possible with C#?

at the moment my child class constructor looks like this:

```
public ChildClass() : base (new List<MyInterface>());
```

Is there a better way without having to new up the List?

Comment: Either define a parameterless constructor in your base class, or pass null/new List to your base class constructor.

Comment: The introduction of a parameter which is mandatory and then working around its necessity can be a hint to a design error.

Comment: But the null argument only works if the base class logic allows it

Comment: There may be better solutions that can be suggested if you show more of your base and child classes. For example, perhaps you should be introducing an interface which your base and child class implements - and your child class would then not inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your base class constructor expects a parameter you have to pass that parameter from Child class.

You have two options.

1. Define a parameterless constructor in base class and then you can avoid passing your parameter. *(Based on comment from @aevitas, if you are going to follow that approach, you may define the parameterless constructor as `protected`, as that will only be available to child classes)*

Like:

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public BaseClass() // or protected
   {
     //does nothing
   }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
public ChildClass() : base ();
```

or  just

```
public ChildClass() //Since base() would be called implicitly.
```

2. The other option is what you are using now, You can pass a new empty instance of your list or `null` as per your requirement.

You should also revisit your design. Not having a parameterless constructor in the base class implies that the class object requires that particular parameter to to work. Working around it is a [code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279121/what-is-the-accepted-definition-of-a-code-smell).

Comment: If you're going about it that way, it may be worthwhile to declare the parameterless constructor as `protected`, to ensure that specific constructor is only used by derived types.

Comment: @aevitas, that is a nice suggestion, added that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter-less constructor on your base class that creates the new List for you?  Other than that, no, you have to do that.

You would have two constructors, like this:

```
public BaseClass(List<MyInterface> newList)
{
    //blah blah blah
}

public BaseClass()
{
    var myList = new List<MyInterface>();
}
```

Comment: Also, if this do not disrupt the program, you can pass null as argument to the base class constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your base class must either

```
A) define a parameterless constructor so that you can invoke base()
```

Or

```
B) be ok with accepting a null value for the List<MyInterface> param
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone has said you either need a parameterless constuctor in the base class or you need to pass the parameter. If the parameter is not needed at all in the child class then that could be a code smell.

If you only want your child class to have access to a parameterless constructor and no other you could make it `protected`.

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected BaseClass() : this(new List<MyInterface>()) {
    }
    public BaseClass(List<MyInterface> newList)
    {
        //blah blah blah
    }
}
```